# Uncaught (in promise): TypeError

Tags: angular

In my application with the below components whenever I click on a link (e.g. for editing a bankaccount or creating a new one) I get the following errors. I have no idea where to look at to solve that. How can I proceed? How can I narrow down the error?

> Error columnNumber: 31 fileName:
>   "http://localhost:4300/polyfills.bundle.js line 605 > eval"
>   lineNumber: 824 message: "Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: guard is
>   not a
>   function\nPreActivation.prototype.runCanDeactivate/canDeactivate$<@webpack-internal:///../../../router/esm5/router.js:3962:49\nMergeMapSubscriber.prototype._tryNext@webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js:133:22\nMergeMapSubscriber.prototype._next@webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js:123:13\nSubscriber.prototype.next@webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:96:13\nArrayObservable.prototype._subscribe@webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/observable/ArrayObservable.js:121:17\nObservable.prototype._trySubscribe@webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:177:20\nObservable.prototype.subscribe@webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:165:60\nMergeMapOperator.prototype.call@webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js:97:16\nObservable.prototype.subscribe@webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:162:13\nEveryOperat…"
>   [...]

or

> columnNumber: 31 fileName: "http://localhost:4300/polyfills.bundle.js
>   line 605 > eval" lineNumber: 824 message: "Uncaught (in promise):
>   TypeError: outlet is
>   null\nPreActivation.prototype.setupRouteGuards@webpack-internal:///../../../router/esm5/router.js:3710:17\nPreActivation.prototype.setupChildRouteGuards/<@webpack-internal:///../../../router/esm5/router.js:3659:13\nPreActivation.prototype.setupChildRouteGuards@webpack-internal:///../../../router/esm5/router.js:3658:9\nPreActivation.prototype.setupRouteGuards@webpack-internal:///../../../router/esm5/router.js:3702:17\nPreActivation.prototype.setupChildRouteGuards/<@webpack-internal:///../../../router/esm5/router.js:3659:13\nPreActivation.prototype.setupChildRouteGuards@webpack-internal:///../../../router/esm5/router.js:3658:9\nPreActivation.prototype.setupRouteGuards@webpack-internal:///../../../router/esm5/router.js:3706:17\nPreActivation.prototype.setupChildRouteGuards/<@webpack-internal:///../../../router/esm5/router.js:3659:13\nPreActivation.prototype.setupChildRouteGuards@webpack-internal:///../../../router/esm5/router.js:3658:9\nPreActivation.prot…"
>   [...]

bankaccounts.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { Bankaccount } from '../../../../domain/bankaccount';
import { BankaccountService } from '../../../../services/bankaccount.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'ac-bankaccounts',
  templateUrl: './bankaccounts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bankaccounts.component.css']
})
export class BankaccountsComponent implements OnInit {

  bankaccounts: Bankaccount[];
  bankaccountSelectedId: string | number;
  bankaccountDeletedId: string | number;

  constructor(private bankaccountService: BankaccountService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getBankaccounts();
  }

  selectBankaccount(bankaccountId: string | number) {
    console.log('id of bankaccount selected: ' + bankaccountId);
    this.bankaccountSelectedId = bankaccountId;
  }

  deleteBankaccount(bankaccountId: string | number) {
    console.log('id of bankaccount deleted: ' + bankaccountId);
    this.bankaccountDeletedId = bankaccountId
  }

  getBankaccounts(): void {
    this.bankaccountService.getBankaccounts().subscribe(bankaccounts => this.bankaccounts = bankaccounts);
  }

}
```

bankaccounts.component.html

```
<div>
  <div class="bankaccount-list">
    <ac-bankaccount-item *ngFor="let bankaccount of bankaccounts" [bankaccount]="bankaccount" (bankAccountDeleted)="deleteBankaccount($event)" (bankaccountSelected)="selectBankaccount($event)" [selected]="bankaccount.id == bankaccountSelectedId">
    </ac-bankaccount-item>
  </div>
  <br />
  <a routerLink='./bankaccounts/new' class="pull-right btn btn-success">
    new bankaccount
  </a>
</div>
```

bankaccount-item.component.ts

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Bankaccount } from '../../../../domain/bankaccount';

@Component({
  selector: 'ac-bankaccount-item',
  templateUrl: './bankaccount-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bankaccount-item.component.css'],
})
export class BankaccountItemComponent {

  @Input() selected: boolean;
  @Input() bankaccount: Bankaccount;

  @Output() bankaccountSelected = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() bankAccountDeleted = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  select() {
    console.log('emitting event bankaccountSelected with id ' + this.bankaccount.id);
    this.bankaccountSelected.emit(this.bankaccount.id);
  }

  delete() {
    console.log('emitting event bankAccountDeleted with id ' + this.bankaccount.id);
    this.bankAccountDeleted.emit(this.bankaccount.id);
  }

}
```

bankaccount-item.component.html

```
<div class="fade-in bankaccount-list-entry" [ngClass]="{selected : selected}" (click)="select()">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-11">
      <span>
        <a [routerLink]="['./bankaccounts/edit', bankaccount.id]"
           (click)="$event.stopPropagation();">{{bankaccount.name}}</a>
      </span>
      <br>
      <small>{{bankaccount.iban}}</small>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
      <span (click)="delete(); $event.stopPropagation()"
            class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash trash"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

app.routing.ts

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './welcome/welcome.component';
import { BalanceComponent } from './balance/balance.component';
import { UploadComponent } from './upload/upload.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './notFound.component';
import { configurationRoutes, configurationRoutingComponents } from './configuration/configuration.routing';

export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/welcome', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'configuration', children: configurationRoutes },
  { path: 'upload', component: UploadComponent },
  { path: 'balance', component: BalanceComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },

  {path: '**', redirectTo: ''},
];
export const appRouting = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes
  //  , { enableTracing: true }
);
export const routingComponents = [WelcomeComponent, UploadComponent, BalanceComponent, AboutComponent, PageNotFoundComponent,
  ...configurationRoutingComponents];
```

configuration.routing.ts

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ConfigurationOverviewComponent } from './components/configuration-overview/configuration-overview.component';
import { BankaccountsComponent } from './components/bankaccounts/bankaccounts/bankaccounts.component';
import { BankaccountEditComponent } from './components/bankaccounts/bankaccount-edit/bankaccount-edit.component';

export const configurationRoutes: Routes = [{
  path: '', component: ConfigurationOverviewComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      component: ConfigurationOverviewComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'bankaccounts/edit/:id', component: BankaccountEditComponent,
      data: { title: 'Bankverbindung bearbeiten' },
      canDeactivate: [BankaccountEditComponent]
    },
    {
      path: 'bankaccounts/new', component: BankaccountEditComponent,
      data: { title: 'Neue Bankverbindung anlegen' },
      canDeactivate: [BankaccountEditComponent]
    }
  ]
}];

export const configurationRoutingComponents = [BankaccountsComponent, BankaccountEditComponent];
```

Comment: Did you configure routes?

Comment: just added the route configuration from my application above in this post

Comment: Banging my head against the wall and cannot get the routing to work. On one page ("configuration") two router outlets shall be displayed on top of each other, e.g. bankaccounts on top, categories on bottom. Each outlet would display different components depending on the route (e.g. edit, create new, list). Is this possible at all? If I configure a path only one child but not two can be configured!?